# why is SVG style in chrome devtools inspector uneditable?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an embedded svg in my webpage:

It resides in a div.

```
<div class="svg-button" id = "button1" data-target="section1">


        <svg
        width="27mm"
        height="11.001mm"
        viewBox="0 0 102.04745 41.578557"
        version="1.1"
        id="svg1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs
            id="defs1" />
        <g
            id="layer1">
            <g
            id="g16-91"
            transform="matrix(0.16370677,0,0,0.17737745,801.81209,632.87564)">
            <path
                style="font-size:125.192px;font-family:'Avrile Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'Avrile Serif';text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;fill:#bc9100;stroke-width:44.3593"
                d="m -4523.0554,-3545.0384 q -12.2688,0 -18.6536,-4.8825 -6.2596,-4.8824 -6.2596,-12.7695 0,-3.7558 2.3786,-6.0093 2.3787,-2.3786 6.6352,-2.3786 0.2504,5.1329 2.0031,9.765 1.7527,4.5069 5.3832,7.3863 3.6306,2.7542 9.5146,2.7542 8.3879,0 13.1452,-4.0061 4.7573,-4.1314 4.7573,-11.7681 0,-4.6321 -1.8779,-7.7619 -1.7527,-3.255 -6.0092,-6.0092 -4.1314,-2.7542 -11.5177,-5.7588 -11.6428,-4.7573 -17.4017,-11.1421 -5.6336,-6.3848 -5.6336,-16.6505 0,-7.136 3.5054,-12.1437 3.6305,-5.1328 9.7649,-7.7619 6.2596,-2.7542 14.1467,-2.7542 11.1421,0 17.2765,4.2565 6.1344,4.2566 6.1344,9.765 0,4.0062 -2.7542,6.1344 -2.629,2.0031 -7.1359,2.0031 0,-3.881 -1.3771,-7.5115 -1.252,-3.6306 -4.3818,-6.0092 -3.0046,-2.3787 -8.2626,-2.3787 -7.2612,0 -11.2673,3.881 -4.0062,3.8809 -4.0062,10.3909 0,5.0077 1.7527,8.5131 1.8779,3.3801 6.1344,6.1344 4.2566,2.629 11.5177,5.6336 11.0169,4.5069 17.1513,10.3909 6.1344,5.8841 6.1344,15.5238 0,11.8933 -8.3878,18.5285 -8.2627,6.6351 -22.4094,6.6351 z m 67.2282,0 q -9.5146,0 -13.8963,-4.2565 -4.2566,-4.3817 -4.2566,-15.1482 v -41.8142 h -9.5146 v -5.0076 q 2.2535,0 5.0077,-0.8764 2.7542,-1.0015 4.7573,-3.1298 2.1283,-2.2534 3.5054,-5.5084 1.3771,-3.255 2.2534,-8.0123 h 5.7589 v 15.3986 h 16.4001 v 7.1359 h -16.4001 v 42.1898 q 0,6.3847 2.629,9.3894 2.629,3.0046 6.8856,3.0046 2.2534,0 4.1313,-0.2504 1.8779,-0.2504 3.881,-0.626 v 5.5085 q -1.6275,0.7511 -4.8825,1.3771 -3.255,0.6259 -6.2596,0.6259 z m 39.6858,0 q -8.3879,0 -13.8964,-4.8825 -5.5084,-4.8824 -5.5084,-15.1482 0,-10.0153 7.0107,-14.7726 7.136,-4.7573 21.5331,-5.2581 l 10.3909,-0.3756 v -7.5115 q 0,-4.5069 -0.7511,-7.8871 -0.7512,-3.5054 -3.255,-5.5084 -2.5039,-2.0031 -7.6368,-2.0031 -4.7572,0 -7.2611,1.7527 -2.5038,1.7527 -3.3802,4.8825 -0.7511,3.0046 -0.7511,7.0107 -5.2581,0 -8.0123,-1.7527 -2.629,-1.8779 -2.629,-6.1344 0,-4.3817 3.0046,-7.0107 3.1298,-2.6291 8.2626,-3.7558 5.1329,-1.2519 11.2673,-1.2519 11.5177,0 17.1513,4.8825 5.7589,4.8825 5.7589,16.7757 v 32.4247 q 0,5.2581 1.7526,7.136 1.7527,1.8779 6.0093,1.8779 h 0.3755 v 5.258 h -16.9009 l -2.0031,-10.7665 h -1.0015 q -2.629,3.5054 -5.1329,6.2596 -2.5038,2.629 -5.884,4.2565 -3.255,1.5023 -8.513,1.5023 z m 2.8794,-7.7619 q 7.6367,0 12.1436,-4.6321 4.5069,-4.7573 4.5069,-12.7696 v -10.1405 l -8.0123,0.3756 q -10.6413,0.5007 -14.7726,4.3817 -4.0062,3.7557 -4.0062,11.1421 0,11.6428 10.1406,11.6428 z m 46.0706,6.51 v -5.258 h 0.3756 q 4.2565,0 7.2611,-1.5024 3.0046,-1.6274 3.0046,-7.5115 v -39.0599 q 0,-5.5084 -3.1298,-7.0107 -3.0046,-1.5023 -7.1359,-1.5023 h -0.3756 v -5.2581 h 19.2796 l 2.3786,12.394 h 0.626 q 1.6275,-3.7557 3.5053,-6.8855 1.8779,-3.1298 5.0077,-4.8825 3.1298,-1.8779 8.6383,-1.8779 6.8855,0 10.1405,2.3786 3.3802,2.3787 3.3802,6.7604 0,3.881 -2.7542,6.3848 -2.629,2.5038 -8.8886,2.5038 0,-5.1328 -1.5024,-7.3863 -1.5023,-2.3786 -5.1328,-2.3786 -3.5054,0 -5.8841,2.7542 -2.3786,2.7542 -3.7557,7.0107 -1.3771,4.2566 -2.0031,8.8887 -0.6259,4.5069 -0.6259,8.1374 v 19.6552 q 0,5.5084 3.0046,7.0107 3.1298,1.3772 7.2611,1.3772 h 3.5054 v 5.258 z m 84.8802,1.2519 q -9.5145,0 -13.8963,-4.2565 -4.2565,-4.3817 -4.2565,-15.1482 v -41.8142 h -9.5146 v -5.0076 q 2.2535,0 5.0077,-0.8764 2.7542,-1.0015 4.7573,-3.1298 2.1283,-2.2534 3.5054,-5.5084 1.3771,-3.255 2.2534,-8.0123 h 5.7589 v 15.3986 h 16.4001 v 7.1359 h -16.4001 v 42.1898 q 0,6.3847 2.629,9.3894 2.629,3.0046 6.8855,3.0046 2.2535,0 4.1314,-0.2504 1.8779,-0.2504 3.8809,-0.626 v 5.5085 q -1.6275,0.7511 -4.8825,1.3771 -3.2549,0.6259 -6.2596,0.6259 z"
                id="text30-8-6"
                transform="scale(1.0409165,0.96069186)"
                aria-label="Start" />
            <ellipse
                style="fill:#29c648;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10.7117;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                id="path1-40"
                cx="-4083.6646"
                cy="-1213.4663"
                rx="1.8221785e-12"
                ry="102.90611" />
            <rect
                style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#bc9100;stroke-width:9.36569;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                id="rect29-2-77"
                width="606.35913"
                height="226.45914"
                x="-4893.1724"
                y="-3563.2771"
                ry="64.871353" />
            </g>
        </g>
        </svg>


    </div>
```

Note, the version is 1.1 --> that is what inkscape produces, if i ask it to export to normal, cleaned svg.

Now in chrome or chromium browser dev tool, normally you will be able to click on the styles and edit them. But here I can't, and the values are in italics. Here is picture.

[image]

Even if I try to edit the CSS file with a simple text editor like kate on linux with syntax highlighting on, it will also become italicised.

I tried to google, but google said you can apply CSS on SVg. ChatGPT agreed. But somethings seemstobe missing.

**Question** : What am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit the values in the HTML viewer directly? It might be uneditable in the CSS panel because they're technically HTML attributes (`width="297mm"`), not CSS styles (`style="width:297mm;"`). So the CSS panel is showing you the inferred value from HTML, but not a true CSS value.

Comment: " if I try to edit the CSS file". What CSS file? You have no css applied in either the code you provided, nor in the screenshot shown.

Comment: AS a workaround, you can add the properties to the `element.style` rule. That will not edit the attributes, but overwrite them; presentational attributes get added at the top of the user style sheets, so any user CSS will have a higher specificity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything, svg is just handled like that in chrome.

you can use css file to change the svg, or inserting a css script at runtime.

so making an svg fill red.

```css
svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

you can do other advanced things, say you have a path in your svg, you would do

```css
svg > path {
 stroke: blue;
 stroke-width: 12
}
```

to change the stroke, svg is also treated like the how the DOM is treated.

look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp) to find all the values you can style with css

using `svg` in css will affect all, so refer to your svg via your div or someother element which is id'ed like

```css
#myDiv > svg > path {
 stroke: blue;
 stroke-width: 12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Inspector says, they are ***Attributes Style***

Those values are **NOT CSS** values, they are **attribute** values

`<svg>`

[image]

`<rect>`

[image]

You can **double click** on the **HTML Attribute** and edit the value

[image]

```html
<svg width="27mm" height="11mm">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```